# Extract N values from a column which is a struct within an array within a struct within an array

Tags: sql, arrays, database, apache-spark, struct

Say I have a table with the following structure inside one of the cells:

```
/*
[] = array
() = struct
{} = map
*/

master_array = 
[
  (
    thing_starts: ,
    thing_ends: ,
    main_var: ,
    main_var_desc: {var: , id: , element: }
    main_var_desc_plus: {outcome: , outcome_plus: },
    main_var_desc_ids: {care: [], into: []},
    main_var_process: [
                           (thing_starts: ,       **I want this data point**
                            thing_ends: ,         **and this one**
                            main_var: ,           **and this one**
                            main_var_metrics: {outcome: , outcome_plus: }
                           ), 
                           (thing_starts: ,
                            thing_ends: , 
                            main_var: , 
                            main_var_metrics: {outcome: , outcome_plus: }
                           )
                          ]
  ),
  (
    thing_starts: ,
    thing_ends: ,
    main_var: ,
    main_var_desc: {var: , id: , element: }
    main_var_desc_plus: {outcome: , outcome_plus: },
    main_var_desc_ids: {care: [], into: []},
    main_var_process: [
                           (thing_starts: ,
                            thing_ends: , 
                            main_var: , 
                            main_var_metrics: {outcome: , outcome_plus: }
                           )
                          ]
  )
]
```

As you can see there are structs within arrays within structs within an array. In the same table I have column_1 and column_2 which contain a unique ID for that row, and a date respectively. And the nested array-struct column, shown above, can repeat any number of times (it's not always a fixed number).

I would like to create a new table from this one that includes column_1, and column_2 (that bit's easy) as well as thing_starts, thing_ends, and main_var nested within each master_array. I've added in comments (**I want this data point**, and **and this one**) to the above structure to show you exactly which bits I want.

In the end I would end up with a table with that includes the N values of `thing_starts`, `thing_ends`, and `main_var`, but split out into separate columns so we have `thing_starts_1`, `thing_ends_1`, `main_var_1`, `thing_starts_2`, `thing_ends_2`, `main_var_2`, etc., up to `thing_starts_N`, `thing_ends_N`, and `main_var_N`. The end result being a flat table with one row per ID number and one column per thing_starts for each value of main_var, thing_starts for each value of main_var, and the corresponding main_var names.

I can do the first bit easily, e.g.:

```
select column_1, 
column_2
from table limit 10
```

And my latest attempt at trying to get the main_var, thing_ends, and thing_starts values was something like this:

```
select column_1, 
column_2,
master_array.main_var_process.thing_starts[1],
master_array.main_var_process.thing_ends[1],
master_array.main_var_process.main_var[1]
from table limit 10
```

But clearly this is totally wrong. Any ideas on how I can do what i've described above?

P.S. i'm using Spark with MySQL

Comment: Which dbms are you using?`

Comment: Have edited post at the bottom to say (i'm using Spark)